# Crystal report dotted lines

Tags: excel, crystal-reports

I am creating a crystal report where data is copied from excel and print to a pdf. I want some transactions to be executed in dotted lines. I have given the lines as dotted in crystal report but when I print that in pdf the pdf shows as a straight line without the dots. How can I do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this: https://answers.sap.com/questions/12955152/sap-crystal-reports-sp26-dotted-line-problem.html

Maybe it's a problem with the printer driver.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).